# Pandas element-wise min max against a series along one axis

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max, min, elementwise-operations

I have a Dataframe:

```
df = 
             A    B    C    D
DATA_DATE
20170103   5.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
20170104   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
20170105   1.0  NaN  2.0  3.0
```

And I have a series

```
s = 
DATA_DATE
20170103    4.0
20170104    0.0
20170105    2.2
```

I'd like to run an element-wise `max()` function and align `s` along the columns of `df`. In other words, I want to get

```
result = 
             A    B    C    D
DATA_DATE
20170103   5.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
20170104   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
20170105   2.2  NaN  2.2  3.0
```

What is the best way to do this? I've checked [single column comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009528/get-the-min-of-0-x-element-wise-for-a-column) and [series to series comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989946/creating-an-element-wise-minimum-series-from-two-other-series-in-python-panda) but haven't found an efficient way to run dataframe against a series.

Bonus: Not sure if the answer will be self-evident from above, but how to do it if I want to align `s` along the **rows** of `df` (assume dimensions match)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Data:

```
In [135]: df
Out[135]:
             A    B    C    D
DATA_DATE
20170103   5.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
20170104   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
20170105   1.0  NaN  2.0  3.0

In [136]: s
Out[136]:
20170103    4.0
20170104    0.0
20170105    2.2
Name: DATA_DATE, dtype: float64
```

Solution:

```
In [66]: df.clip_lower(s, axis=0)
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:1247: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
  result = op(x, y)
Out[66]:
             A    B    C    D
DATA_DATE
20170103   5.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
20170104   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
20170105   2.2  NaN  2.2  3.0
```

we can use the following hack in order to ged rid of the `RuntimeWarning`:

```
In [134]: df.fillna(np.inf).clip_lower(s, axis=0).replace(np.inf, np.nan)
Out[134]:
             A    B    C    D
DATA_DATE
20170103   5.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
20170104   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
20170105   2.2  NaN  2.2  3.0
```

Comment: Much cleaner. :)

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the answer but I'm getting a bunch of Nan values. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: To complete the answer, obviously to align on the row one just need to set `axis=1`. As @MaxU mentioned earlier, making sure index and column name match between the DataFrame and Series is very important for this to work.

Comment: btw, is there a way to suppress or get around that RuntimeWarning presumably due to the NaNs in the original dataframe?

Comment: @Zhang18, i think it's because of NaN's. You can try this dirty hack: `df.fillna(np.inf).clip_lower(s, axis=0).replace(np.inf, np.nan)`

Comment: Turns out as long as there is at least one column without `NaN`, then `clip_lower` doesn't throw an error on the entire operation. Feels like a bug. I'll try to submit an issue request on GitHub.

Comment: Upon further investigation the error has little to do with `NaN`s. It is thrown the first time if there are `NaN`s but is mute upon running the same `clip` command for subsequent times. An issue has been opened on Github: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16378

Answer (score 10):

This is called broadcasting and can be done as follows:

```
import numpy as np
np.maximum(df, s[:, None])
Out: 
             A    B    C    D
DATA_DATE                    
20170103   5.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
20170104   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
20170105   2.2  NaN  2.2  3.0
```

Here, `s[:, None]` will add a new axis to `s`. The same can be achieved by `s[:, np.newaxis]`. When you do this, they can be broadcast together because shapes `(3, 4)` and `(3, 1)` have a common element.

Note the difference between `s`  and `s[:, None]`:

```
s.values
Out: array([ 4. ,  0. ,  2.2])

s[:, None]
Out: 
array([[ 4. ],
       [ 0. ],
       [ 2.2]])

s.shape
Out: (3,)

s[:, None].shape
Out: (3, 1)
```

An alternative would be:

```
df.mask(df.le(s, axis=0), s, axis=0)

Out: 
             A    B    C    D
DATA_DATE                    
20170103   5.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
20170104   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
20170105   2.2  NaN  2.2  3.0
```

This reads: Compare df and s. Where df is larger, use df, and otherwise use s.

Comment: Don't sell yourself short @ayhan, this is a great answer. Learned about broadcasting and comparing a series to a dataframe. Thank you!

Comment: @pshep123 Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

While there may be better solutions for your problem, I believe this should give you what you need:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = pd.concat([df[c], s], axis=1).max(axis=1)
```